# How can I output an <img> wrapped in a list and anchor?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm attempting to pull in some pics from flickr to my site and created an unordered list similar to the following using random images from the feed.

This should look something like:

```
<li><a href='#'><img src='imagesource'/></a></li>
```

I'm only seeing the `<img='imagesource'/>` being loaded to the page.

Here's what I've got so far...any help would be appreciated:

```
if (i <= defaults.limit-1)
{
    var large = (item.media.m).replace('_m.jpg', '_b.jpg');

    // Assign the image with attributes
    flickrImage = $("<img/>").attr({
        src: large,
        class: "gal-image"
    });

    // Push flickr images into array
    flickrImages.push(flickrImage);
}

$('.gal-image').prepend('<li><a class="slide-img" data-lightbox="random" href="' + large + '">');
$('.gal-image').append('</a></li>');
```

Comment: what's your problem? You don't know how to append it to your page, or something else?

Comment: the images are being populated to the page, but only <img src='imagesource'/> is showing up. The li and a tags aren't being appended.

Comment: where did you put it to the page? I didn't see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var flickrImage  = $("<img>").attr({
        "src": large,
        "class": "gal-image"
    }).on("load", function(e) {
  $(this)
  .wrap("<li><a class=slide-img data-lightbox=random href=" + this.src + ">");
});
// as pointed out at comments , not appear where `img` inserted into document ?
$("body").append(flickrImage);
```

```js
var img = $("<img>").attr({
        "src": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200",
        "class": "gal-image"
    }).on("load", function(e) {
  $(this)
  .wrap("<li><a class=slide-img data-lightbox=random href=" + this.src + ">");
  $("body").prepend($(this).parents("li")[0].nodeName)
});
$("body").append(img);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`prepend` and `append` do so inside the element, not around it. Let's just redo the logic a tiny bit, and it'll all be fixed.

```
$('.gal-image').appendTo('<a class="slide-img" data-lightbox="random" href="' + large + '">').parent().appendTo('<li>');
```

There, done! `appendTo` will add the set inside the set given to the argument. In this case, we append it to an `<a>` created on the fly. We then add the image's parent (`<a>`) to an `<li>` created right here.

Answer (score 1):

The [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) method inserts content **inside** each element in the set of matched elements, at beginning and end respectively. It doesn't wrap the content around the matched element.

For wrapping an element with an `HTML` structure,

Use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method as follows:

```
$('.gal-image').wrap('<li><a class="slide-img" data-lightbox="random" href="' + large + '"></a></li>');
```

> The .wrap() function can take any string or object that could be passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure. This structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost element. A copy of this structure will be wrapped around each of the elements in the set of matched elements

P.S: `jQuery` creates `DOM` elements using the `HTMLString` and inserts into `DOM`, it doesn't insert closing tags...